# How to create std::ofstream file with binary data in the memory without writing it to storage?

Tags: c++, ofstream

How can i create a binary file in a memory using string data i have already in the memory.

I have written following code to create a .jpg file using string stream i have in the memory. it's working 
fine. but in there i have to create a file in the storage.

```
std::string file_name_temp = "temp.jpg";
std::ofstream out_file_temp(file_name_temp.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
out_file_temp << std::hex << image_data;
out_file_temp.close();
```

Currently i am reading file from the memory again and load it to GUI application.
This works.
But I need to avoid this write to the storage and instead create a .jpg file in the memory itself, and load to the UI. is there anyway to achieve the above functionality?

My image data is in string format.

Comment: `std::stringstream`?

Comment: @genpfault how to define  std::ios::binary  flag with std::stringstreams ? and and if any way could you direct me to get a little bit more clarification? any way thanks to quick response.

Comment: `std::stringstream` has [constructors that accept an `openmode` parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream), just like `std::ofstream` does. But in any case, a `stringstream` is just a wrapper for `std::string` data in memory, and `std::string` can hold binary data. Though, you really should consider finding (or making) an `ostream`/`istream` class that can work with raw memory directly. If your image data is already in memory, and you just want to load it using a stream, there is no good reason to have to make a copy of the data just to stream it